# Constant error: "Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."

Tags: sql

For the last few weeks I have been getting the same message when logging on to phpMyAdmin, which prevent me from making any updates to or deleting specific lines.

I get the following notice:

"Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."

Is this a known issue? Can I get around it?

Any advice/help much appreciated,
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

did you check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748073/phpmyadmin-4-0-5-grid-edit-checkbox-edit-copy-and-delete-features-are-not-a

> To fix this, pick a suitable column(s) in your table and create a
>   unique index on it (or on them). Version 4.0 added this verification
>   to avoid other problems when not the intended row is modified or
>   deleted.
>
> See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key.